# NoClassDefFoundError When Debug Android Engine Connected Android Project

Tags: android

I’m struggling on a problem on my new Android C2DM test project: 
**Android Engine Connected Android Project.** 
The problem is:

At LogCat:
 **04-04 19:35:09.414: E/AndroidRuntime(320): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMessaging**

Location at debug window:  **InvocationTargetException.class**
InvocationTargetException.(Thrownable) Line 50

Exception: **NoClassDefFoundError**

1. Does any one have any idea what file (and where) I’m missing and how to fix?
2. Know where/how to get Google API source for debugging?

Really appreciate your inputs.

Comment: What is the target SDK of your app? C2DM is available for API 8 and above (Android v2.2).

Comment: I did try Google API 8 and 10; and I use ADT 17. Help-> Check Update shows few items for me to update. I'm currently updating now and will try again to see what happens. Thank you MisterSquonk and TacB0sS! Any one got the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the latest ADT doesn't allow libraries (.jar) in any other folder except "libs" so please rename the folder from "lib" to "libs" and then add the existing three libraries (.jar) again.

Comment: Thank you so much Wen. Good hints and I will find time and go back to test.